# Is the staging_dir of openwrt the only requirement to cross compile application?

Tags: cross-compiling, openwrt

i'm using openwrt as a toolchain for a mips device. Everything work well, but the openwrt dir is more than 1 Go, so id' like to keep only what is necessary to build programs.

Is the staging_dir the only requeriment, or should i keep other dir or the whole openwrt directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply keep the `staging_dir` if all you need is the cross-compilation toolchain, e.g. CC, LD, AR, RANLIB, etc.

However if you want to build or pull packages from the feeds, you need to keep the entire OpenWrt SDK directory.